# AEM 6.2 how to access OSGI config which are defined with-in servlet itself

Tags: aem

I have created an AEM servlet. Now I have created OSGi configuration (MULTI_FIELD as shown below of type array) with-in servlet itself because its defined as service also. Now, my requirement is how to access this osgi config inside doGet method. here is the code of servlet.

```
@Component(label = "Sample Servlet", description = "Sample Servlet", immediate = true, metatype = true)
@Service
@Properties(value = {
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.resourceTypes", value = { 
    GlobalConstants.RES_TYPE,
            GlobalConstants.PAGE_RES_TYPE }, propertyPrivate = 
 true),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.selectors", value = { 
 GlobalConstants.PAGES,
            GlobalConstants.ASSETS }, propertyPrivate = true),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.extensions", value = "xml", 
 propertyPrivate = true),

    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = { "GET" }) })

public class SampleServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {


 @Property(value={"English", "Hindi"}, unbounded = 
 PropertyUnbounded.ARRAY, label = "Subjects", cardinality = 50, 
 description = "Example for Multi field config") 
 private static final String MULTI_FIELD = "multifield";

    @Override
protected void doGet(final SlingHttpServletRequest request, final 
SlingHttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of property to a member field within activate method:

```
@Activate
protected void activate(final BundleContext bundleContext, 
                        final Map<String, Object> componentConfig) {
   this.multiField = (String[]) componentConfig.get(MULTI_FIELD);
}
```

I didn't try the code myself but it can give some idea. You can check Sling Main Servlet here to see how it works: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/tags/org.apache.sling.engine-2.2.6/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/engine/impl/SlingMainServlet.java

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Emin that this should be handled inside the activation method. But on 6.2 the overwritten method has only one parameter and I would use [PropertiesUtil](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/commons/osgi/PropertiesUtil.html) instead of the cast.

The method would look like:

```
    @Activate
    public void activate(final ComponentContext componentContext) {
        final Dictionary<?, ?> props = componentContext.getProperties();
        this.multiField = Arrays.asList(PropertiesUtil.toStringArray(props.get(MULTI_FIELD), new String[0]));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am able to use the activate method with two different parameters on 6.2.0.SP1-CFP3 as per Emin approach. Do you foresee any issue with this?

Comment: I thought that this was deprecated and depended on the SCR version. But as I've found out this is not true: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-925. So you may safely use Emins method signature, pass directly the properties map or even no params at all (but then you could not access the properties :) ).